# It comes full circle

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, sequence

Top, Middle, Bottom, Double-Right;
Double-Right;
Up Left, Middle, Double-Right;
Double-Right;
Top, Middle, Bottom, Up Left, Down Right;
Top, Middle, Bottom, Up Left, Double-Right;
???

> What would fit next?

Comment: It's late and so my sense of humour is quickly fading, but might the answer be "CRISS CROSS! Everybody clap your hands!" ? (I'll see myself out...)

Comment: Does the middle always refer to the same thing?

Comment: @DrXorile Yes, each unique directional basically refers to the same thing.

Comment: @El-Guest I thought the exact same thing - especially with the lyrics "Right foot 2 stomps" = double-right but alas, the rest doesn't fit

Comment: Although an answer has been selected, I am QUITE certain that this is how you fly in Tony Hawk's Pro Skater 2

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The next sequence is

> **Top, Middle, Bottom, Up-Right, Down-Left**
>
>  The instructions are components of a seven-segment-display readout. The numbers being spelled out are digits of pi (thus the title) , and the next digit is 2

This is illustrated by

> [image]

Comment: Very well done, and Welcome to Puzzling.SE! I'll award you "Answer Accepted" check mark after a little while.

Comment: Also, +1 for free hand drawing, especially the red circle! :)

Comment: I am appalled at the lack of votes.

Comment: Oh haha I understand the title hint now!

Answer (score 4):

> Fire (3 rockets from fully loaded rocket launcher) !

Details:

> That pattern looks exactly like **a player playing Unreal Tournament 3**. More exactly, it's circling a target while dodging damage. Except the rest of the standard movements, the double one is the double jump which can be used to evade damage. During the time the maneuvers are performed, the player loads its rocket launcher so it can shoot 3 rockets at the target (or the goo gun/Bio-Rifle, same thing, still requires time to fully load it's secondary mode).

Comment: I had to lookup Unreal Tournament 3 on YouTube. Looks like it might be fun, but I didn't base my question on it and don't really understand how it applies.

Comment: All the things in your initial posting are the movements done (directional keys used)by any players playing that game. The Double-Right is called a combo (pressing right twice fast) and makes you dodge-jump in that direction. it works in any direction. Using such a dodge in a single direction is good for circling an enemy while evading its return fire. This is just something that perfectly fits the answer since no specific context was initially stated. Although all the others work in most FPSs, the dodge / double jump combo is specific to UT.